# ResponseEntity как вернуть структуру, а не только тело?

Tags: java, spring, rest

В унаследованном коде используется не обычный RestController, а javax.ws.rs, где запросы выглядят так:

```
@GET
@Path("/data")
@RequestMapping(consumes = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody()
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUpdatedIssue(@RequestBody String body) {
    return ...
}
```

При отправке запроса, полученный результат выглядит таким образом:

```
"headers": {},
"body": [], //38 items
"statusCode": "OK",
"statusCodeValue": 200
```

Сейчас идет переход на @RestController с @GetMapping и в таком случае,  отправляя запрос, полученный ответ выглядит уже как простой массив.

Запрос:

```
@GetMapping("/data")
public ResponseEntity<?> handleUpdatedIssue() {
    return ...
}
```

Ответ:

```
[] //38 items
```

Структура с headers, body и прочим команде понравилась больше, т.к. при ошибке можно отправить данную ResponseEntity с codeValue 4xx и обработать "body" также, как и при успешном запросе (не нужно проверять, есть тело запроса или нет)

**Вопрос** - как добиться, чтобы ответ не приходил как массив или текст, а имел данную структуру?

Comment: Десеариализируй вручную при помощи ObjectMapper и верни String

Comment: `полученный ответ выглядит уже как простой массив` - где выглядит? Как вы его смотрите?

Comment: @RomanKonoval при отправке через Chrome / Postman

Comment: @GlebKuznetsov спасибо, вроде похоже на правду

Comment: Сдается мне, что дело всего лишь в том, как ответ отображается в postman. В body же возвращается то же самое или вы изменили формат? Возможно, дело в том, что теперь вы стали возвращать другой content-type и postman показывает вам его иначе.